# Laravel image cannot be fetch

Tags: laravel, store

I'm currently doing the laravel CRUD, I need to upload an image to the database and display it. but now the image cannot be fetched. I already posted the problem before but didn't get a working solution. Hope this time somebody will help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6022.png).Someone said there is also an error on the controller, kindly double-check the store function.

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    $lostitem =new Admin();
    $this->validate($request, [
        'date' => 'required',
        'TimeFound' => 'required',
        'AreaWhereFound' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
        'Remark' => 'required',
        'DateClaimed' => 'required',
        'TimeClaimed' => 'required',
        'CategoryID'=>'required'
    ]);

    $uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();

    $lostitem->code = $uuid;
    $lostitem->date = $request->date;
    $lostitem->TimeFound = $request->TimeFound;
    $lostitem->AreaWhereFound = $request->AreaWhereFound;
    $lostitem->image = $request->image;

    if($request->hasfile('image')){

        $filenameWithExt=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename=pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension =$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore=$filename.'_'.date("yyMdHHmm")  .'.'.$extension;
        $path=$request->file('image')->move(public_path('images/'),$fileNameToStore);
    }
    else{
        $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
    }

   // $lostitem->image = $request->image ;
    $lostitem->Remark = $request->Remark;
    $lostitem->DateClaimed = $request->inputDateClaimed;
    $lostitem->TimeClaimed = $request->TimeClaimed;
    $lostitem->CategoryID = $request->CategoryID;
    $lostitem->save();
    return redirect(route('LostItem_list'))->with('successMsg', 'Record added!');
}

//the view
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('title', 'View LostItem Record')
@section('content')
<a href="{{ route('LostItem_add') }}"  class="btn btn-primary">Add lost item</a>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @if(session('successMsg'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{ session('successMsg') }}
            </div>
        @endif
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>TimeFound</th>
                <th>AreaWhereFound</th>
                <th>Item </th>
                <th>Remark</th>
                <th>DateClaimed</th>
                <th>Time Claimed</th>
                <th>CategoryID</th>
                <th>Date Added</th>
                <th>Last Update</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($lostitem as $item)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $item->date }}</td>t
                        <td>{{ $item->TimeFound }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->AreaWhereFound }}</td>
                        <td><img src="{{ asset('images/' . $item->image) }}" alt="image"></td>
                        <td>{{ $item->Remark }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->DateClaimed }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->TimeClaimed }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->CategoryID }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->created_at->format('Y-m-d g:i a') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->updated_at }}</td>
                        <td>
                        <a  href="{{route('LostItem_edit', $item->code) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                             <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </a>
                        <form method="POST"
                            action="{{ route('LostItem_delete', $item->code) }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            {{ method_field('delete') }}
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure?');">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: What do you in response?

Comment: Could you show the result from inspect element? To see the final src attribute.

Comment: thanks for the response, may I know how to show the result? I'm new on programming

Comment: @Alber Ramos, I have already attach an image above. it will show the result of the codes

Comment: @JUSTINCHUA I mean right clck on the image element, click inspect element and show the screenshot like this https://i.imgur.com/c4UbMmZ.png

Comment: appreciate your help, I have already solved the problem.Thank you so much. t

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are making a mistake by directly storing image like

`$lostitem->image = $request->image;`

Because here $request->image will be object of a file, not a string so here is a complete code that you need to implement.

```
if($request->hasfile('image')){

    $filenameWithExt=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename=pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension =$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileNameToStore=$filename.'_'.date("yyMdHHmm")  .'.'.$extension;
    $path=$request->file('image')->move(public_path('images/'),$fileNameToStore);
}
else{
    $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
}

//Store only image name and then fetch image as url
$lostitem->image = $fileNameToStore;
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I have try your suggestion but it didn't work. maybe there is other   error I did not found out

Comment: did you check that your image get stored in your path correctly??

Comment: yes , the image was properly stored at both public/images folder and the database

Comment: can you post full path of the image stored in your sytem??

Comment: can you the path that is render in html via inspecting the element??

Comment: may I know how to do that? I have attach an image above, maybe that's what you are looking for

Comment: by just right clicking on the broken image and select inspect element from the menu. and find the path.

Comment: http://localhost:8082/myshop/images/iphone_2020Apr2008080404.jpg 
if I do it correctly, here it is